# Wrong charges returned by Australian Post API?

Tags: php, api, post

I'm trying to provide users of my site with postage calculator and to do so need to pull out data from australian post API (http://drc.edeliver.com.au/ratecalc.asp), but what is returned dosen't look anything like what  get at Australian post website calculator at http://auspost.com.au/apps/domestic-parcel.html

I've tried with different settings, countries etc. and nothing seems to work. Data is returned with no error but charge and number of days makes no sense. E.g.

http://drc.edeliver.com.au/ratecalc.asp?Pickup_Postcode=2216&Destination_Postcode=0800&Country=AU&Weight=600&Service_Type=STANDARD&Length=300&Width=300&Height=200&Quantity=1

When same data calculated at AustPost page 
http://auspost.com.au/apps/domestic-parcel.html
gives me much higher charge.

I would like to avoid going thru sourcecode of countless modules for various shopping carts and so if anyone could point out what am I missing here that would be very much appreciated. btw I'm using php with curl.

Comment: Why do you believe the data doesn't make sense? Your API link says the charge would be 13.15, and the Postage Assessment Calculator does the same (settings: From 2216 to 0800, Weight >500g - 1kg, Dimensions 30,0cm x 30,0cm x 20,0cm, Regular Parcel)

Comment: well this is embarassing.. I kept typing in 600 gram (constantly missing one additional 0) in my code, but on AustralianPost site I was providing 6kg. Your comment solved my problem, if you could make it into an answer I will be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you believe the data doesn't make sense? Your API link says the charge would be 13.15, and the Postage Assessment Calculator does the same (settings: From 2216 to 0800, Weight >500g - 1kg, Dimensions 30,0cm x 30,0cm x 20,0cm, Regular Parcel)